# Help wiring a GFCI outlet with multiple wires in the box

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, gfci

I was replacing/upgrading some electrical outlets in my house to GFCI. I did two of them, the third one is in the garage. The box has an outlet and a poll switch, I went to replace it but the outlet has 4 white wires, 2 black wires and a red. (*Maybe because the switch is a 3 way switch?*)

I broke the original outlet taking wires out. After trying to figure out the wiring diagram it started to get dark. I can't use the lights because power is off.

I couldn't figure out the GFCI wiring. So had an extra old outlet around and wired it for safety.

I need advice on how to wire it?

*When I go back to the house   I will take pictures.*

Comment: So I was replacing/upgrading some electrical outlets in my house to GF. I did to of them. The 3rd one is in the garage. The box has an outlet and a poll switch. I went to relace it but the outlet has 4 white wires. 2 black wires and a red. Maybe because the switch is a 3 way switch? 

I broke the orginal outlet taking wires out. After trying to figure out the wiring diagram it started to get dark. I can't use the lights because power is off. I couldn't figure out the GFCI wiring. So had an extra old outlet around and wired it for safty. Anyways anyone know how to wire it?

Comment: We'll definitely need some pictures of the wiring and of the broken outlet showing the tabs.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box as well as the broken outlet please?

Comment: If the red wire went to 1 side of the original receptacle so it was switched on 1/2 this has a different connection setup than a 3 way are there 2 switches that control the same things?  Taking photos prior to taking wires apart is always a good idea even pros Mark wires and take photos when the box is a mess. GFCI receptacles can’t be split it’s all or nothing.

Comment: Are you installing 1 GFCI receptacle device *per outlet*, or do you plan to use the downline protection feature to also protect plain outlets? Will you be applying the "GFCI Protected" sticker to those outlets?  If this all went over your head, that is fine, it just affects the answer.